# Show that a set of $\alpha$-Holder functions is compact

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, holder-spaces

> Let $(K,d_K)$ be a compact metric space and consider $Z=\mathbb{R}^d$, with the usual metric. Let $L,\alpha>0$ and $(t,z_0) \in K\times \mathbb{R}^d$. Show that the set $$\mathcal{H}_{L,\alpha,t_0,z_0}=\{f:K\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^d:\ f \text{ is } \alpha\text{-Holder with constant } L \text{ and } f(t_0)=z_0\}.$$ is a compact set of $C:=C((K,Z),d_C)$.

It is clear that $\mathcal{H} \subset C$. Showing compactness, for me, is the hard part. First of all, I tried to show that $\mathcal{H}$ is bounded and closed, then, I realized that I do not have that $\mathcal{H} \subset\mathbb{R}^d$, so I tried other path: showing that $\mathcal{H}$ is sequentially compact. My proof comes and I am not certaing of it, was:

> > Consider $\{f_n\} \subset \mathcal{H}$ a sequence. Then, for $x \in K$, $$||f_n(x)-z_0||\leq L\cdot d_K(x,z_0)^\alpha$$ Since $K$ is compact, then, bounded, the sequence $\{f_n(x)-z_0\} \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is bounded and so it is $\{f_n(x)\} \subset \mathbb{R}^d$, since $z_0$ is fixed. Then, it has a convergent subsequence $\{f_{n_k}(x)\}$, where $f_{n_k}(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ for all $x \in K$.From here, I concluded that $f_{n_k} \rightarrow f$, with no more arguments (and I do not think is such direct). Then, the problem was just showing that $f \in \mathcal{H}$, which is also clear.

Could someone give me a hand with other solution or showing me what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $d_C$ is the $\sup$-metric. Let $f \in \mathcal{H}$ be arbitrary. Then, for all $x \in K$
$$
\lVert f(x) \rVert \leq \lVert f(t_0) \rVert + \lVert f(t_0) - f(x) \rVert \leq \lVert z_0 \rVert + Ld(t_0, x)^\alpha \leq \lVert z_0 \rVert + LC^\alpha,
$$
where $C := \sup_{y, z \in K} d(y, z)$. $C$ is finite, because $K$ is compact and therefore bounded. So all coordinate functions $f_i$, $i \in \lbrace 1, ..., d \rbrace$ are bounded by the same constant $\lVert z_0 \rVert + LC^\alpha$ that is **independent** of $f$.

Now let $\varepsilon > 0$ and $\delta := \left(\frac{\varepsilon}{L}\right)^\frac{1}{\alpha}$. Then, we have for all $x, y \in K$ that fulfil $d(x, y) < \delta$:
$$
\lvert f_i(x) - f_i(y) \rvert \leq \lVert f(x) - f(y) \rVert \leq Ld(x, y)^\alpha  < L\delta^\alpha = \varepsilon
$$
So all coordinate functions are uniformly continuous with $\delta$ chosen **independently**  of $f$.

So according to [Arzelà-Ascoli's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem), for every sequence $(g^{(j)})_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathcal{H}$, there exists a subsequence (that we again denote by $g^{(j)}$) and some $g \in C(K, Z)$ such that the former subsequence converges to $g$ in $d_C$. We have to prove that $g \in \mathcal{H}$. But this is easy: Convergence in $d_C$ implies pointwise convergence and therefore for all $x, y \in K$ where $x \neq y$:
$$
\frac{\lVert g^{(j)}(x) - g^{(j)}(y) \rVert}{d(x, y)^\alpha} \leq L \overset{j \rightarrow \infty}{\implies} \frac{\lVert g(x) - g(y) \rVert}{d(x, y)^\alpha} \leq L
$$
This is Hölder-continuity. Especially we have
$$
g^{(j)}(t_0) = z_0 \overset{j \rightarrow \infty}{\implies} g(t_0) = z_0.
$$
We are done.

**Remark**: I know that Wikipedia only states Arzelà-Ascoli's theorem for $d = 1$. But you can construct a convergent subsequence for the first coordinate function, then a sub-subsequence for the second and so on.

Comment: I have a doubt: Arzelà-Ascoli requires equicontinuity and "pontually totally bounded". It is clear for me your proof for equicontinuity, however, it seems that you've prooved that $\mathcal{H}$ is bounded, and not totally bounded. What am I missing?

Comment: @Anyway142 you miss that this holds for ANY $f$ and $x$. Therefore you can apply $sup_x$ and then $sup_f$ to get $\sup_f sup_x \lVert f(x) \rVert \leq \lVert z_0 \rVert + LC^\alpha$. This is exactly the proporty that we need

Comment: after some thinking, I saw your point. Could you just validate it? Your proof sees that $\mathcal{H}$ is bounded, and so it is $\mathcal{H}(t)$. Since $\mathcal{H}(t) \subset \mathbb{R}^d$, then, we have a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$, which is totally bounded. Did I got it? By $\mathcal{H}(t)$ I mean that, given $t \in K$,  $\mathcal{H}(t):=\{f(t): f \in \mathcal{H}\}$

Comment: Arzelà-Ascoli's theorem requires that there is some constant $M>0$ such that $\lvert f(x) \rvert \leq M$ for all $x \in K$ and $f \in \mathcal{H}_{L, \alpha, t_0, z_0}$. If this condition and equicontinuity of all functions in  $f \in \mathcal{H}_{L, \alpha, t_0, z_0}$ is given, then every sequence in $\mathcal{H}_{L, \alpha, t_0, z_0}$ has a convergent subsequence in $C(K, Z)$ w.r.t. $d_C$.